# ' input string was not in a correct format. ' insert date with dataa set in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i going to create Mobile Store Site in Asp.net

i create i insert page in asp.net . and using dataset for insert product . but

when i clcick the button for adding in database . show me [this errpr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jp4Cy.png)

how i resolve it ?

[this my data base](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SksqF.png)

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    PersianCalendar pc = new PersianCalendar();
    String datetime=pc.GetYear(DateTime.Now) + "/" + pc.GetMonth(DateTime.Now) + "/" + pc.GetDayOfMonth(DateTime.Now);
    String time = DateTime.Now.Hour + ":" + DateTime.Now.Minute;


    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataSetTableAdapters.tblproductTableAdapter da = new DataSetTableAdapters.tblproductTableAdapter();


   da.InsertQuery(int.Parse(txtprotitle.Text), txtprotitle.Text, txtexplain.Text, decimal.Parse(txtproprice.Text), txtprolink.Text, Session["userid"].ToString(), datetime, time);

    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
}
```

this my dataset

```
INSERT INTO [tblproduct] ([pid], [title], [explain], [price], [link], [uid], [date], [time]) VALUES (@pid, @title, @explain, @price, @link, @uid, @date, @time)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure  Session["userid"] is not null

Answer (score 1):

You should implement like this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

PersianCalendar pc = new PersianCalendar();
String datetime=pc.GetYear(DateTime.Now) + "/" + pc.GetMonth(DateTime.Now) + "/" + pc.GetDayOfMonth(DateTime.Now);
String time = DateTime.Now.Hour + ":" + DateTime.Now.Minute;


DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataSetTableAdapters.tblproductTableAdapter da = new DataSetTableAdapters.tblproductTableAdapter();
int pid;
decimal gheymat;

if(int.TryParse(txtprotitle.Text, out pid) &&  decimal.TryParse(txtproprice.Text, out gheymat))
{
da.InsertQuery(pid, txtprotitle.Text, txtexplain.Text, gheymat, txtprolink.Text, Session["userid"].ToString(), datetime, time);

Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");}
else{
//error with parsing
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the stacktrace, your problem is not in the date but in this part:

```
int.Parse(txtprotitle.Text)
```

You need to double check `txtprotitle` and make sure it is a number and in the range of Int32. A Safe way to deal with this **(other than client-side validation which is very recommended)**

```
int title;

if(int.TryParse(txtprotitle.Text, out title) == false)
{
    // failed to convert - Do Something about it.
}
```

Then:

```
da.InsertQuery(title, txtprotitle.Text, 
               txtexplain.Text, decimal.Parse(txtproprice.Text),                            
               txtprolink.Text, Session["userid"].ToString(), datetime, time);
```

You might need to do the same for `txtproprice.Text` but using `decimal.TryParse`.